# Parse mailto urls in Python

Tags: python, mailto, url-parsing

I'm trying to parse mailto URLs into a nice object or dictionary which includes `subject`, `body`, etc. I can't seem to find a library or class that achieves this- Do you know of any?

```
mailto:me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody
```

Comment: using the `re` module could be a fast solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might just want to write your own function to do this.

Edit:
Here is a sample function (written by a python noob).

Edit 2, cleanup do to feedback:

```
from urllib import unquote
test_mailto = 'mailto:me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody'

def parse_mailto(mailto):
   result = dict()
   colon_split = mailto.split(':',1)
   quest_split = colon_split[1].split('?',1)
   result['email'] = quest_split[0]

   for pair in quest_split[1].split('&'):
      name = unquote(pair.split('=')[0])
      value = unquote(pair.split('=')[1])
      result[name] = value

   return result

print parse_mailto(test_mailto)
```

Comment: You should probably use `.split(sep, 1)` to limit to one split, and save the results instead of splitting multiple times.  Plus, you will need `urllib.unquote()` to decode `%xx` placeholders in the query string keys and variables.

Answer (score 4):

You can use urlparse and parse_qs to parse urls with mailto as scheme. Be aware though that according to [scheme definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto):

```
mailto:me@mail.com,you@mail.com?subject=mysubject
```

is identical to

```
mailto:?to=me@mail.com&to=you@mail.com&subject=mysubject
```

Here's an example:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
from email.message import Message

url = 'mailto:me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody&to=you@mail.com'
msg = Message()
parsed_url = urlparse(url)

header = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
header['to'] = header.get('to', []) + parsed_url.path.split(',')

for k,v in header.iteritems():
    msg[k] = ', '.join(v)

print msg.as_string()

# Will print:
# body: mybody
# to: me@mail.com, you@mail.com
# subject: mysubject
```

Answer (score 2):

The core urlparse lib does less than a stellar job on mailtos, but gets you halfway there:

```
In [3]: from urlparse import urlparse

In [4]: urlparse("mailto:me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody")
Out[4]: ParseResult(scheme='mailto', netloc='', path='me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

**EDIT**

A little research unearths [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417958/parse-custom-uris-with-urlparse-python). Bottom line: python url parsing sucks.

Comment: Why it does not catch the query part beats me, tho'

Comment: Tried this- doesn't seem to do anything but grab the scheme

Comment: It should also url-decode the chunks. No big feat, but still.

Comment: `urlparse()` returns correct result see [rfc3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)

Comment: Going to an RFC for the subject matter is really strange, but it so happens that urlparse is not even correct with regard to the RFC or its own documentation, since it purports to separate the query part - but does not. 

"URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]"

Comment: url with # wont be parsed. ex `domain.com/value#additional_data` behind # will be muted

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the re module...

```
import re

d={}
def parse_mailto(a):
  m=re.search('mailto:.+?@.+\\..+?', a)
  email=m.group()[7:-1]
  m=re.search('@.+?\\..+?\\?subject=.+?&', a)
  subject=m.group()[19:-1]
  m=re.search('&.+?=.+', a)
  body=m.group()[6:]

  d['email']=email
  d['subject']=subject
  d['body']=body
```

This assumes it is in the same format as you posted. You may need to make modifications to better fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Batteries included: [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: Doesn't work- urlparse result = `ParseResult(scheme='mailto', netloc='', path='me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody', params='', query='', fragment='')` - Does not read subject/body/etc

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib

query = 'mailto:me@mail.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody'.partition('?')[2]
print dict((urllib.unquote(s).decode('utf-8') for s in pair.partition('=')[::2])
           for pair in query.split('&'))
# -> {u'body': u'mybody', u'subject': u'mysubject'}
```

Comment: Thanks bladerunner, this works too- Gave it to Robert because he was first

Answer (score 0):

You shold use special library like that

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urlinfo

and contribute and create issue to make Python better ;)

P.S. Does not use Robbert Peters solution bcz it hack and does not work properly. Also using a regular expression is using super BFG Gun to get small bird.

Answer (score 0):

I like Alexander's answer but it is in Python 2! We now get `urlparse()` and `parse_qs()` from `urllib.parse`. Also note that sorting the header in reverse puts it in the order: to, from, body.

```py
from email.message import Message
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

url = Path("link.txt").read_text()
msg = Message()
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
header = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
header["to"] = header.get("to", []) + parsed_url.path.split(",")

for k, v in sorted(header.items(), reverse=True):
    print(f"{k}:", v[0])
```

I am just using this as a one-off, when I used `msg.as_string()` I got some strange results though so I just went with the string. The values are lists of one value so I access the 0'th entry to make it a string.