# Reading outlook popup email

Tags: python, selenium, outlook, automation

In a website I am testing using python, we have a "contact us" button,
that should pop up an outlook email window ready to be sent.
Its body should contain a certain text.
Users should have outlook installed.

I want 3 things, but dont know how:

1. To wait for the outlook email window to pop up
2. Read the content
3. Close the email window

Read about win32com.client, but not sure how
to use it in this case

Comment: You're really testing the browsers handling of a certain type of link, this is a bit beyond what selenium was intended for. You want to look into a framework like AutoIT.
You'll need to hook into the host OS and, this is likely out of scope for what you actually want to test.

Comment: Does it really pop-up specifically Outlook email window? I would rather expect just a `mailto:` link, which opens the email program (or even website like gmail) of user's preference. You could test this approach more easily – read the URL the app redirects to, check if it's a mailto link, and parse the text, subject... See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9067638/7292139) for more details on parsing

Comment: Yes, When user click on "contact us" button an outlook(currently) email box should be opened.I want to get and validate the text contained in it's body.
How should I test that?

Comment: Can you post your current code please