# Python one liner for extracting url from text

Tags: python, regex, stdin

My goal is to write one liner for extracting URLs from text. The problem is that I'm not even able to read data from STDIN. My experiments so far:

```
└──> grep -i http: flashgot.log | python -c 'import sys; import re; for line in sys.stdin: print line'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; import re; for line in sys.stdin: print line
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


└──> grep -i http: flashgot.log | python -c 'import sys; import re; x = [print line for line in sys.stdin]'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; import re; x = [print line for line in sys.stdin]
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Second plan was to use some of advises from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417958/parse-custom-uris-with-urlparse-python) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python)

Comment: Python is whitespace delimited. There are also no semicolons

Comment: not sure what your restrictions are, but you can use pickle to load and execute arbitrary code in one line

Comment: my goal is to write quick and dirty script without needing to store it on HDD or something else.

Comment: why even use python?

Comment: @cricket_007 [yes there are](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: @bereal - guess I didn't know python as well as I thought. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelXu because I know how to do with perl or awk but not in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your snippet working by using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`:

```
grep -i http: flashgot.log | python -c 'import sys; import re; [sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % line) for line in sys.stdin]'
```

I think the problem was not with reading stdin but more with finding the correct syntax to use on one line. On trying your scripts, it looks like `for` doesn't work as a block in the single-line syntax, and neither does `print` within a list-generator.

PS: While trying one-line functions, I find that [`lambda`](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) comes in handy sometimes. You might find it useful later in your script

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way how to explicitly set beginning and end of block?

Comment: @WakanTanka Not that I know of: I'm also only just experimenting; I haven't managed to find any documentation on the one-liners yet...